# Why does my TransactionScope not work?

Tags: c#, .net, database, msdtc

I have code that looks like this:

```
using (TransactionScope tsTransScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    bcAdvertiser.SaveToTraffic();
    bcAdvertiser.SaveToDb();

    tsTransScope.Complete();
}
```

The moment I do anything with the database, like open a connection, I get this error:

`{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004D01B): The Transaction Manager is not available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D01B)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Boolean& nodeNameMatches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle& whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()}`

So I went into Component Service, right-clicked on My Computer, selected Properties, went into the MSDTC tab and the only thing I get is this:

[image]

I don't get the traditional dialog with Security options and all that.  I tried switching to a remote MSDTC coordinator of the actual box where SQL Server is running (by click on the Select button), which is a Windows Server 2003 R2 box.

I also checked the setup on the remote box and all is good.  This used to work on Windows 7, but now with Windows 8.1 update 1, it does not.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Yes the tsTransScope is in a using block but where are you actually using it?

Comment: @Blam Last line before the block end (`tsTransScope.Complete();`)

Comment: Good you completed the transaction.  Where does anything join that transaction?  Does the code you posted actually throw an error?  Why post the error for when you open the connection and not post the code where you open the connection?

Comment: @Blam Both bcAdvertiser.SaveToTraffic() and bcAdvertiser.SaveToDb() open connections and execute stored procedures.  Yes, the code does throw an error but deep down in the call to bcAdvertiser.SaveToTraffic() (when it attempts to open a connection).